# How to POST JSON with Jersey WebResource.Builder?

Tags: java, json, post, jersey

I wanna POST a JSONOject or a Map using a Jersey Client with a WebSresource.Builder.

```
WebResource.Builder builder = res.type(mediaType);
uploadResult = builder.post(ClientResponse.class, new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

How do I pass the JSON the right way to the POSt request? How the JSON/Map has to be converted?

//cheers

Comment: do you really need to serialize a simple hashMap? Not an object or something?